# Android Show Custom Nav and Footer on Tap Like ImageViewer

Tags: android

I want to show activity full screen and want to **Show/Hide** **Custom Title bar** with back button and **footer** with one button only. Just like **Full screen Image Viewer Android**
like If my activity is :

[image]

When i touch and tap anywhere in screen it should be like:

[image]

### Update

---

I have searched a lot but haven't find proper solution. I want do with **Android 4.2 Jelly Bean (API level 17)**.

I got a solution **[Immersive Full-Screen Mode]**[3](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) but this is for **Android 4.4 KitKat (API level 19)**.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this now:

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#f2af2a" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    RelativeLayout rlMain;
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rlMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1500);

        rlMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    if (!(getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility() == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE)) {
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                    }
                }
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3500);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the lean back function introduced in Android 4.4 KitKat

Comment: Hmmmm, this site: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/whats-changed-in-android-4-4-kitkat/
???

Comment: I want to do with 4.2.2 :(

Comment: @Jamm dude, I've edited the code, it works on emulator!

Comment: @Jamm I've checked in KitKat, can you try in JellyBean?